# Read multiple excel files from google drive using Java

Tags: java, android-studio, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Currently, I have this code to read data from Excel files.
The Excel files are located in Google Drive.

```
for (File excelFile : excelFiles) {                
    String range = "A3:E55";
    ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                 .get(excelFile.getId(), range)
                 .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    // the rest of the code ...
}
```

Because I have ~100 files to read, it's taking a long time to read them all.
I tried to use threads to make it faster, and it worked, but I got a quota error.

Is there an option to get a list of responses with 1 command?